# how to get 50 largest files in directory CMD

Tags: file, sorting, cmd, command, window

If I run in CMD

dir /od

I get sorted files by length. But now, do anyone know what is a command to get the 50 largest file?

Thank you so much for help.

Branka

Comment: In order, largest first, and numbered for you too: `dir /b /a:-d /o:-s | findstr /n "^" | findstr /b "[123456789]: [1234][0123456789]: 50:"`

Answer (score -1):

This combined command could satisfy you.

```
du -a /od | sort -n -r | head -n 50
```

## du

```
--all  -a                 (Write size for all files)
```

## sort

```
--numeric-sort  -n  (Compare string numerical value)
--reverse  -r                      (Reverse results)
```

Comment: This answer does not currently take account of the [[tag:cmd]] tag, as many of the commands you're using, do not exist in the Command Prompt, used in the Windows and OS/2 Operating Systems mentioned in its descriptive text.